# 8 digit web color in xml

Tags: xml, colors

I found a color definition in an xml file which looks like this `#8867d1fd`. I wanted to check it in e.g. Photoshop color picker but it keeps cutting two last digits. What kind of notation is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colors are defined as 6 digits (red and green and blue components of the color) and the extra 2 digits are alpha which is the degree of transparency. this is useful if you want to show your content and the background as well. 0 alpha means transparent, FF means solid and the background will not be shown. any number in between means semi-transparent or semi-solid.

so the format is:

```
ARGB ( alpha , red , green and blue )
```

to check your color use #67d1fd to check the color without alpha.